# Android download file Out of Memory

Tags: android, file, byte

I'm trying to download a file from internet. It works well, but if the file is larger than 2MB I get this error. Thanks for your help

```
    09-13 17:49:05.228 17994-18110/? E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 286-byte allocation.
09-13 17:49:06.322 17994-18111/? E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 16-byte allocation.
09-13 17:49:07.361 17994-17994/? E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 72-byte allocation.
09-13 17:49:08.408 17994-18003/? E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 24-byte allocation.
09-13 17:49:09.447 17994-18003/? E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 28-byte allocation.
09-13 17:49:09.994 17994-18111/? E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 28-byte allocation.
09-13 17:49:10.541 17994-17994/? E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 28-byte allocation.

 public static byte[] is2Bytes(InputStream is) {
    byte[] buf = null;
    BufferedInputStream bufIS = null;
    if (is != null)
        try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bufIS = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        buf = new byte[4096];
        int cnt;
        while ((cnt = bufIS.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            byteBuffer.write(buf, 0, cnt);
        }
        buf = byteBuffer.size() > 0 ? byteBuffer.toByteArray() : null;
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bufIS != null) bufIS.close();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
    }
    return buf;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to download the entire file into memory. This will not work for large files, as you will not have heap space for a large contiguous block of RAM.

Write the file to disk instead, or use the memory in chunks (e.g., download 4K, consume the 4K, discard the 4K, repeat).

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: @user2847219: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v7.6/Service/Downloader/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/downloader/Downloader.java#L52-L73